# ';' Expression expected | public boolean in if else

Tags: java, android, if-statement, boolean, expression

)

```html
[...]

else if (id == R.id.nav_videovorschlag) {

            public boolean isOnline() {
                ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo netInfo = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

                if(netInfo == null || !netInfo.isConnected() || !netInfo.isAvailable()){
                    return false;

                    ImageButton internetok;
                    offlineDialog.setContentView(R.layout.onlinepopup);
                    internetok = (ImageButton) offlineDialog.findViewById(R.id.internetok);
                    internetok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            offlineDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }
                return true;

                setTitle("Videovorschlag");
                Fragment5_vorschlag fragment = new Fragment5_vorschlag();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag_home, fragment, "Videovorschlag");
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }

[...]
```

AndroidStudio says that there `public boolean isOnline() {` is an expression expected (;).
But that's wrong... Can anybody help me to fix this problem... I stuck on it since one hour :-(.

Best regards

Comment: Why do you not trust the error message? Why do you think you can write a function in the middle of another function (you can't)?

Comment: You’re declaring a method within another method; unless you are using an anonymous class or lambda that is strictly not allowed.

Comment: This is invalid syntax, plain and simple. You define the `isOnline` method in the middle of some other code, this is not how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
[...]

else if (id == R.id.nav_videovorschlag) {
          if(isOnline){
setTitle("Videovorschlag");
                Fragment5_vorschlag fragment = new Fragment5_vorschlag();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag_home, fragment, "Videovorschlag");
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
             }
            }

public boolean isOnline() {
                ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo netInfo = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

                if(netInfo == null || !netInfo.isConnected() || !netInfo.isAvailable()){
                    return false;

                    ImageButton internetok;
                    offlineDialog.setContentView(R.layout.onlinepopup);
                    internetok = (ImageButton) offlineDialog.findViewById(R.id.internetok);
                    internetok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            offlineDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }
                return true;
}
```